# How to block user switch in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

The arrival of android Lollipop give me some troubles.
The pinning screen and user switch doesn't seem to be lockable although the application has Administrator rights.
Apparently, there is only Device owner that can properly manage profiles and users.

My application can't use the Device owner because I can't limit to the NFC enabled devices.

I'm searching for solutions that could block the user switch and pinning screen functionalities while the app is Device Admin.

Thank you.